# Line Spacing Inside the Table in Word Using Apache POI

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, alignment, vertical-alignment, line-spacing

https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/fbe67397-658c-4b04-b295-b0d6759e1aaa.jpg

Hello Everyone I need to add **Line spacing Before**(Spacing about **6pt**) effect **inside the table**.You can see the above image that has a paragraph spacing i need that effect. I am using 5.0.0 version. And checked on many sites. nothing useful. if someone help me that will be great. **Thank You** in advance :)

Comment: "That makes the content inside the table to be align in center.": No, it does not. Do using [XWPFTableCell.setVerticalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign-) to do so.

Comment: It aligned Top Center of the cell. I want it in the Middle Center of the cell. That's why I needed that line spacing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the paragraph spacing `apache poi` provides [XWPFParagraph.setSpacingBefore](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setSpacingBefore-int-) and [XWPFParagraph.setSpacingAfter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setSpacingAfter-int-). Measurement unit for the `int` is twentieths of a point. So `8*20` is `8 pt`.

In a table one needs get the first paragraph of a `XWPFTableCell` to set spacing before:

```
...
XWPFTableRow tableRow = ...
...
XWPFTableCell cell = tableRow.getCell(1);
if (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) cell.getParagraphs().get(0).setSpacingBefore(8*20);
...
```

But if the requirement is vertical aligning in cell, then [XWPFTableCell.setVerticalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign-) should be used. But this only can be rendered properly if there is no spacing after the last paragraph which pushs the paragraph upwards.

So

```
...
XWPFTableRow tableRow = ...
...
XWPFTableCell cell = tableRow.getCell(1);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
if (cell.getParagraphs().size() > 0) cell.getParagraphs().get(cell.getParagraphs().size()-1).setSpacingAfter(0);
...
```